# azure blob client returns file not fully

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

i'm trying to download file from azure blob storage, but it returns only part of file. What i'm doing wrong ? File in storage is not corrupted

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetFile(string fileName)
{
    var blobClient = BlobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
    var downloadInfo = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
    byte[] b = new byte[downloadInfo.Value.ContentLength];
    await downloadInfo.Value.Content.ReadAsync(b, 0, (int)downloadInfo.Value.ContentLength);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: What version of BlobStorage nuget package are you using? I dont know of any apis where the client exposes a download method. You always need to get the container and then call download. Is `BlobContainerClient` your own wrapper?

Comment: This is SDK version 12.

Comment: It is quite possible for `ReadAsync` method to read less than the bytes requested. You may want to read the content in a loop till the time you reach the end of the stream. See this link for an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=netcore-3.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.4.2 package. I tried this code and it works for me

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetFile(string fileName)
{
    var blobClient = BlobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
    using (var memorystream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(memorystream);
        return memorystream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to full understand your code as the current BlobClient as of v11.1.1 does not expose any download methods. As [@Guarav Mantri-AIS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri-ais) mentioned the `readAsync` can behave in that manner.

Consider an alternative using the `DownloadToByteArrayAsync()` which is part of the API. I have include the code required to connect but of course this is just for the purpose of demonstrating a full example.

Your method would be condensed as follows:

```cs
public async Task<byte[]> GetFile(string containerName, string fileName)
{
    //i am getting the container here, not sure where or how you are doing this
    var container = GetContainer("//your connection string", containerName);

    //Get the blob first
    ICloudBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

    //and now download it straight to a byte array
    return await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
}

public CloudBlobContainer GetContainer(string connectionString, string containerName)
{
    //1. connect to the account
    var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

    //2. create a client
    var blobClient = _account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    //3. i am getting the container here, not sure where or how you are doing this
    return = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
}
```

Comment: Your solution is based on the older version of the SDK which may not be acceptable to OP. You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobdownloadinfo?view=azure-dotnet.

Comment: Thanks I missed the comment mentioning v12